# How to get the updated props immediately after service call in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In component I want to get the data immediately in props after calling
webapi service call and do some operation,but issue is that it is not
updating the props immediately because as we know that call will be
async, So what will be the solution? My codes in component are like
this:-

```
openPreviewClick=(event) => {
 this.props.GetReport();
 console.log(this.props.reportData);
}

function mapStateToProps (allReducers) {  
return {reportData: allReducers.reportData 
}}

const matchDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  GetReport: () => dispatch(LoadReportData())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(MyContainer)
```

> Now I have to open a pdf for this I have tried with two solution:-
>
> 1. Handling life cycle of the page

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 if(nextProps.reportPath!=undefined){
   window.open(nextProps.reportPath,"thePop","menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,status=1,top=280,width=850,height=600");
}
```

> 2. Writing the code in render

```
render () {
 if(this.props.reportPath!=undefined && this.props.reportPath!=""){}
      window.open(this.props.reportPath,"thePop","menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,status=1,top=280,width=850,height=600");
}
```

openPreviewClick is my button click on which I want to access the
props named as reportData.But console.log(this.props.reportData); is
giving me the null value for the first time,second time if I will
click then we are getting the data.How we can manage this? I already tried above two solution but it is not working.

Comment: Disable button until data is available.

Comment: while fetching data show spinner, or render null

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer, you don't ^1

If this is truely an async request, there is no guarantee when the data will come back, so your component needs to "understand" that is can exist in a "without data" state.

Simplest form of this is:

```
render() {
    if( ! this.props.reportData) return null;

    // normal render code, at this point we have data
    return <div>{this.props.reportData.map(foo, ...)}</div>
}
```

A better form, would be something like:

```
render() {
    if( ! this.props.reportData) {
        return <div><img src="loading.gif" /></div>;
    }

    // normal render code, at this point we have data
    return <div>{this.props.reportData.map(foo, ...)}</div>
}
```

*^1 Note: You could technically use async functions, but I feel that would complicate the problem, especially without a fundamental understanding of what is already going on.*

Comment: I donot want to render any html on the button click event, I want some other functionality like opening pdf, generating CSV file and download, so in this scenario your solution will fail. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Changing the question is pretty poor form. Regardless, the solution holds true - if the report data isn't ready it can't be accessed. Your new question is much closer to a solution - componentWillReceiveProps is probably the way to grab that

Answer (score 0):

In your main file where you create the store you can dispatch action and set initial value just like

```
import configureStore from './store/configureStore;
import {LoadReportData} from './actions/LoadReportData';

const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(LoadReportData());
```